# Fence against a river

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I make the following diagram. The problem is to make a river.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried, what does your current code look like? Questions like this, that look like "please do this complicated thing for me" tend not to get answers because they require a great deal of effort on the part of the community. To make the most of this site, it would help if you made some substantive efforts please and show what you have done so far with a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a random river. Change `\pgfmathsetseed` for a different river.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[lime!70!olive](0,0)rectangle(8,4);
\clip(0,0)rectangle(8,4);
\draw[red, very thick, text=black](2,1)--node[above left]{$x$}(2,3)--node[above]{$y$}(6,3)--node[above right]{$x$}(6,1);
\pgfmathsetseed{14159}
\draw[decorate, decoration={random steps, segment length=3mm, amplitude=1pt}, lime!70!black, line width=.5mm, double=cyan!60!white, double distance=1cm](-1,1)--node[above=9mm, text=black]{A}(9,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. How can I add some waves and shade to the river/lake.